# How do I use a custom cookie session serializer in Rack?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm currently integrating [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) into a new Rack application I'm building. I'd like to implement a [recent patch](https://github.com/rack/rack/issuesearch?state=closed&q=session#issue/70) to Rack that allows me to specify how sessions are serialized; specifically, I'd like to use `Rack::Session::Cookie::Identity` as the session processor.

Unfortunately, the documentation is a little unclear as to what syntax I should use to configure `Rack::Session::Cookie` in my rackup file, can anyone here tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**config.ru**

```
require 'my_sinatra_app'

app = self

use Rack::Session::Cookie.new(app, Rack::Session::Cookie::Identity.new), {:key => "auth_token"}

use Warden::Manager do |warden| # Must come AFTER Rack::Session
  warden.default_strategies :password
  warden.failure_app Jelli::Auth.run!
end

run MySinatraApp
```

**error message from thin**

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `new' for #<Rack::Session::Cookie:0x00000110124128>
```

PS: I'm using bundler to manage my gem dependencies and I've likewise included rack's master branch as the desired version.

**Update:** As suggested in the comments below, I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb); sadly the suggested syntax in the docs is not working.

**Update:** Still no luck on my end; offering up a bounty to whoever can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'my_sinatra_app'

app = self

session_app = Rack::Session::Cookie.new(app, {
        :coder => Class.new {
                def encode(str); str; end
                def decode(str); str; end
              }.new
      })

use session_app

run MySinatraApp
```

I had a look at the source code, and Rack::Session::Cookie::Identity is as simple as:

```
class Identity
  def encode(str); str; end
  def decode(str); str; end
end
```

then this should suffice. I've run it under thin and I get a hello world app up - that's as far as I went.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is in the `app` variable?

Comment: Sorry this is a code snippet based on your `require 'my_sinatra_app'; app = self`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've been messing around with it some more, turns out the `use session_app` is what was screwing me up. I've found that the session app adds itself to the rack stack when you instantiate a new `Rack::Session::Cookie` class within the rackup file, which also explains why I was getting an undefined method error from thin. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of Rack::Session::Cookie ( https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb )

You can see there are no initialize method and it propose to use :

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                           :domain => 'foo.com',
                           :path => '/',
                           :expire_after => 2592000,
                           :secret => 'change_me'
```

Comment: Sadly, that syntax doesn't work. My problem is that I need a new (non-default) instance of the `Rack::Session::Cookie` class that doesn't use the `Abstract::ID` encoder internally. Also, in the same documentation you referenced, you can see the syntax they suggest for using `Rack::Session::Cookie::Identity`, which is what I'm currently attempting to use.